# ignore value of select option jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is probably quite simple but I am wondering how to ignore value from an `option select` if it is equal to a certain value, for example I have this select

```
<select>
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value=".Dog">Dog</option>
  <option value=".Cat">Cat</option>
</select>

$('select').on('change', function() {
 var animal_type = $('option:selected').text();
});
```

So if 'All' is selected I do not want to assign anything to the `animal_type` variable so that in the following ajax post `animal_type` is disregarded and **not sent** as a parameter

```
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/public/rehomed',
   data: {
     animal_type: animal_type, #so if ALL selected this should not be passed through
     rehomed: false,
  }
 });
```

The reason I am thinking to remove the `animal_type` variable from the ajax post is the parameters of the post make an SQL query on the server side for me in rails.

Comment: couldnt you just set `animal_type` to `null` or `0` and then on the server side end you could catch it there?

Comment: I guess that you want to avoid the ajax call at all ? Just put an **if** around the $.ajax....

Comment: sorry guys, i have updated my question with why i am trying to do this

Comment: @Richlewis Why are you passing text and not value instead? It would be better instead, e.g: `var animal_type = this.value;`

Comment: because my values are set to .Dog for example (using mixitup js to filter results), the text is taken from the values in my db (basically pulling all unique values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition to check the value of the selected option before you do the AJAX.

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    var animal_type = $('option:selected').text();
    var data_send = {animal_type: animal_type, rehomed: false,};
    if(animal_type != "All"){ 
      data_send = {rehomed: false,};
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/public/rehomed',
        data: data_send,
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
var animal_type = $('option:selected').text() == "All" ? null : $('option:selected').text();
```

or you can modify html like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="-1">All</option>
  <option value=".Dog">Dog</option>
  <option value=".Cat">Cat</option>
</select>
```

and in js:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {

    var animal_type = $(this).val();  // get value
    if (animal_type != -1)   // if All is not selected send selected option text
    {
    animal_type = $(this).text();
    }
    else
    {
     animal_type = null;     // in case All selected set it null
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid sending the animal type if the value is "":

```
var myData  =  { rehomed: false};
if (animal_type != "All") {
     myData.animal_type = animal_type;
}
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/public/rehomed',
   data: myData
});
```

**Note** that you have

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
 var animal_type = $('option:selected').text();
});
```

So it looks like the **animal_type** has a local scope [won't be accessible outside the **onchange** function].

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
 var animal_type = $('option:selected').val();
 var sending_data;
if(animal_type == '')
   sending_data = {rehomed: false}
}
else
{
  sending_data = {animal_type: animal_type, rehomed:false}
}
   $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/public/rehomed',
   data: sending_data,
 });
});
```